# What does .template do?

Tags: c++

I have a few lines of code like this:

```
ac_fixed<Wfl, Ifl, true> input_mant;
      // Set the sign bit to zero to ensure a positive value.
      input_mant[Wfl - 1] = 0;
      // Set the bit adjacent to the sign bit to 1 to ensure a normalized mantissa
      input_mant[Wfl - 2] = 1;
      // Set the remaining bits to the bit pattern stored in the last (Wfl - 2) bits in mant_i.
      input_mant.template set_slc(0, mant_i.template slc<Wfl - 2>(0));   // <<< SYNTAX ERROR: 'template'
```

In which ac_fixed type is defined as:

```
template<int W, int I, bool S=true, ac_q_mode Q=AC_TRN, ac_o_mode O=AC_WRAP>
class ac_fixed : private ac_private::iv<(W+31+!S)/32>
#ifndef __SYNTHESIS__
__AC_FIXED_UTILITY_BASE
#endif
#ifdef __AC_FIXED_NUMERICAL_ANALYSIS_BASE
, public __AC_FIXED_NUMERICAL_ANALYSIS_BASE
#endif
... (a lot more skipped)
```

During compiling, the line input.mant_template has "syntax error: 'template'". I don't know what .template does in this case and why it has a syntax error? And not sure where to look inside ac_fixed definition. The files are from the Algorithmic C HLS library in case a full visibility is needed.

Comment: "Template names can not only occur after a :: but also after a -> or . in a class member access". So the troubled line is trying to use set_slc in input_mant's template, correct? If so, why that line is an error? mant_i is another template class

Comment: That line needs to be changed to "input_mant.set_slc(0, mant_i.template slc<Wfl - 2>(0));".